# Flutter : Cloud Firestore upload progress indicator

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I have a list of items in a catalog page with an add button. When I click the add button, it takes me to a form where I can upload an image and description. When I hit save, the data gets saved asynchronously to firebase. While the data is being saved, a progress bar is displayed on the screen and page is popped when done and takes me back to the catalog page.

What I would like to do is pop the form page right away on save and show save progress as in the catalog page. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create bloc or a cubit of some kind that will carry out the upload mechanism. Once you hit save, you'll have a bloc event that will start the upload and emit state according to the upload progress.

Since the upload is taken care of by the bloc you can pop the form page right after clicking save and have a bloc builder of some kind that will show the progress on the catalog page.

This bloc will be shared by both the pages, so you'll have to use dependency injection in my opinion.